# Ionic Grid Layout Alignment Not Correct

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, flexbox, ionic3

I am trying to expand one Grid column to 2 columns width.. but not expanding properly.. see below
[Currently Showing Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9XYu.png)

[image]

this is my HTML...

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="ion-padding">
    <ion-grid>
    <ion-row align-items-center>
        <ion-col size="12"><input type="text" class="calculation_view" readonly value="0"></ion-col>
    </ion-row>
      <ion-row class="calculator_digits" align-items-center>
        <ion-col>C</ion-col>
        <ion-col>DEL</ion-col>
        <ion-col>/</ion-col>
        <ion-col>*</ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row class="calculator_digits" align-items-center>
        <ion-col>7</ion-col>
        <ion-col>8</ion-col>
        <ion-col>9</ion-col>
        <ion-col>-</ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row class="calculator_digits" align-items-center>
        <ion-col>4</ion-col>
        <ion-col>5</ion-col>
        <ion-col>6</ion-col>
        <ion-col>+</ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row class="calculator_digits" align-items-center>
        <ion-col>1</ion-col>
        <ion-col>2</ion-col>
        <ion-col>3</ion-col>
        <ion-col>=</ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row class="calculator_digits" align-items-center>
        <ion-col size="6">0</ion-col>
        <ion-col size="3">.</ion-col>
      </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

CSS...

```
ion-row.calculator_digits{

    ion-col{
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 4px;
        background: #607d8b;
        border: none;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 8px;
        font-family: monospace;
    }
}

input.calculation_view {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 25px;
    background: #607d8b;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Also See this demo image one which i am following...
[Original Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVxR1.png)

[image]

How do i set the equal (=) column to take 2 column height?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do that in ionic's grid, since they use `flex` to structure their grid system. Flex, unline Grid, cannot be multi-directional (i.e, both vertical and horizonal). To achieve this, I would've used grids.

In order to use grid, I first set the parent's display as `grid`. After that, I set the sizes for each column (in the example below, I set `60px` for each column).

Then, I "put" `.zero` and `.equals` in their specific locations using `grid-[row|column]-[start|end]` and that's pretty much it:

```css
#calculator {
  --size: 60px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: var(--size) var(--size) var(--size) var(--size);
  grid-gap: 8px;
}

button {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 25px;
  background: #607d8b;
  border: none;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

button.zero {
  grid-row-start: 5;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}

button.equals {
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 5;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
  <button>C</button>
  <button>&lt;</button>
  <button>/</button>
  <button>X</button>
  <button>7</button>
  <button>8</button>
  <button>9</button>
  <button>-</button>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
  <button>6</button>
  <button>+</button>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button class="zero">0</button>
  <button>.</button>
  <button class="equals">=</button>
</div>
```